# How to handle error In $.get()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jquery code in which I am using get() and calling some remote url/file. 
Now I want to know what the best way is to handle errors from this.

What I am doing is:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            error: function(x, e) {

                if (x.status == 0) {
                    alert(' Check Your Network.');
                } 
                   else if (x.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested URL not found.');

                } else if (x.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internel Server Error.');
                }  else {
                    alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
                }
            }
        });

        $.get("HTMLPage.htm", function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#mydiv').html(data);

        });
    });
```

This is working fine.But want to know is there any better way of doing this?

ref:http://www.maheshchari.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling/

Comment: That's a decent AJAX error handling for me.

Comment: Define better? What is wrong with your existing code that you want to improve?

Comment: If you want to improve your code, you could stop using alerts and use functions that do something more user friendly. You are actually the only one that wants to see this error information. You could show a modal screen or a little textbox somewhere, telling the user that an error occurred.

Answer (score 26):

As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR," returned by $.get() implements the Promise interface, giving it all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise.

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function() {
    alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

Comment: Simple and to the point. This should be the accepted answer !

Comment: My code is using the `$.get` function, and I was wondering how to add the error handling. This solution is perfect for my case. +1

Answer (score 22):

Using $.ajaxSetup is global for all ajax calls. Because the $.get function doesn't have any error callbacks, defining an error handler in $.ajaxSetup is the only way to handle errors.  If you use $.ajax, you can define the error handler in the $.ajax call like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "HTMLPage.htm",
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $('#mydiv').html(data);        
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 0) {
      alert(' Check Your Network.');
    } else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 404) {
      alert('Requested URL not found.');
    } else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 500) {
      alert('Internel Server Error.');
    }  else {
       alert('Unknow Error.\n' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }     
  }
});
```

This is specific to only this ajax call, that way you can have more specific error messages.  But using the global error handler works just as well.

You could define your functions outside of the $(document).ready() like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: AjaxError
    });

    $.get("HTMLPage.htm", GetSuccess);
});

function AjaxError(x, e) {
  if (x.status == 0) {
    alert(' Check Your Network.');
  } else if (x.status == 404) {
    alert('Requested URL not found.');
  } else if (x.status == 500) {
    alert('Internel Server Error.');
  }  else {
     alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
  }
}

function GetSuccess(data) {
  alert(data);
  $('#mydiv').html(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing such a great response to this question! I especially appreciated the tip about moving the function definitions outside of the $.ajaxSetup() call.

Answer (score 1):

copy/paste from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/:

> statusCode(added 1.5) {} 
>   A map of numeric HTTP codes and
>   functions to be called when the
>   response has the corresponding code.
>   For example, the following will alert
>   when the response status is a 404:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   statusCode: {404: function() {
>     alert('page not found');
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> If the request is successful, the
>   status code functions take the same
>   parameters as the success callback; if
>   it results in an error, they take the
>   same parameters as the error callback.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, the call is `$.ajaxSetup` then `{ statusCode: ...}` etc.