# jQuery .get error response function?

Tags: jquery

Thanks to StackOverflow, I managed to get the following code working perfectly, but I have a follow up question.

```
$.get('http://example.com/page/2/', function(data){ 
  $(data).find('#reviews .card').appendTo('#reviews');
});
```

This code above enabled my site to fetch a second page of articles with a Load More button in WordPress. However when the site runs out of pages/results, I'm running into a small issue. The load more button remains in place. It will keep trying to fetch data even if no pages are remaining.

How can I tweak this command so that I can show a visual response if the `.get` request fails or is a (404) not found page for instance?

If someone could help me out with a simple example of even an `alert("woops!");` that would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: $.ajaxSetup Function Works like charm , its the best option for $get - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175756/how-to-handle-error-in-get

Answer (score 196, accepted):

`$.get` does not give you the opportunity to set an error handler.  You will need to use the low-level [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/page/2/',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){ 
        $(data).find('#reviews .card').appendTo('#reviews');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('woops!'); //or whatever
    }
});
```

---

**Edit March '10**

Note that with the new [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object) object in jQuery 1.5, you can set an error handler after calling `$.get`:

```
$.get('http://example.com/page/2/', function(data){ 
    $(data).find('#reviews .card').appendTo('#reviews');
}).fail(function() {
    alert('woops'); // or whatever
});
```

Comment: You don't have to do this, there are other alternatives with `$.ajaxSetup()` and the `ajaxError` global event.

Comment: Does fail have any details about why it failed?

Answer (score 34):

If you want a generic error you can setup all [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (which [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) uses underneath) requests jQuery makes to display an error using [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), for example:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert("An AJAX error occured: " + status + "\nError: " + error);
  }
});
```

Just run this once before making any AJAX calls (no changes to your current code, just stick this before somewhere).  This sets the `error` option to *default* to the handler/function above, if you made a full [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call and specified the `error` handler then what you had would override the above.

Comment: Doesn't work, I get this alert: An AJAX error occured: error
Error:

Comment: Use console.log instead of alert() : 

```console.log("An AJAX error occured: " + status + "\nError: " + error);```

Answer (score 14):

You can get detail error by using responseText property.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
alert("An AJAX error occured: " + status + "\nError: " + error + "\nError detail: " + xhr.responseText);
     } 
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can chain `.fail()` callback for [error](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#entry-longdesc) response.

```
$.get('http://example.com/page/2/', function(data){ 
   $(data).find('#reviews .card').appendTo('#reviews');
})
.fail(function() {
  //Error logic
})
```