# is there a timeout when using Jquery/ajax/jasonresult on large data sets?

Tags: jquery, json

---

***updated info

I now do not believe this is a timeout issue. But something does seen to create a server error ("500"). I've tested with various sets of data and once the size goes over some threshhold, the ajaxError function is called. The server queries a db for rows of data and turns those into an XML string. The db has a one--many set of tables that create the recursivly constructed xml string. The parent table has 2300 rows and the child table has about 20000 - so the string is rather large. BUT, this function works fine if I use code like this:

```
    <form id="theTax" method="post" action="ProcessTax" >
@{
    TaxonomyHelper th = new TaxonomyHelper(1);
    @Html.Raw(th.TaxonomyDivTag.ToString())        
 }
</form>
```

So, in this case, a silly amount of data is returned and while it takes over a minute to render (done recursively on the client)...it works. My goal was to leverage ajax and divide and conquer depending on the user's needs (always a significant subset of this full dataset). My only curiosity was why, when I do the same thing using ajax, jquery and json, do I get this server error? And more importantly, is there some limit that I should check for before asking for a dataset size too big to succeed???

So in today's testing, when I sub-divide the set to a limit of some smaller size, I do not get an error. And it always works or does not work - as if it measured what the server said was coming across the wire and said "nope" when that size restriction is hit. I have tried delays, sitting on a breakpoint and other silly measures - I've tried to carve up the level 2 xml nodes in various forms by adjusting the linq2sql query... no matter what, it always works or always does not work.

So the question now is: DOES ANYONE KNOW OF A TOTAL DATA SIZE LIMITATION ON WHAT COMES BACK FROM A SERVER CALL FOR A "getJSON" CALL? It seems that this is true as the relative size of success vs. failure seems pretty close. I'd need to add some code to measure size but if someone knows this, that'd be faster :)

thanks again for the swags but I now do believe this may be of value rather than me learning something new about jquery, ajax and how to spell json ;)

---

The code snippets below are part of a MVC3 app. The JasonResult returned by URL (a function named "GetJson") returns html that is displayed in a div tag. The JasonResult function called "GetJason" returns a rather small number of chars - approx 10K. "GetJasonAll" is a rather large number of chars - well in excess of 100K. They are both renderings of a large taxonomy.

I trying to find the reason for why the smaller version of the JasonResult works fine while the other fails to display the data. When using the jquery ajax features, I've tried async, sync and a few other ideas - all to no avail. It seems to act like it times out. But I know the function is returning the data from the JasonResult controller function. But it seems to die there - as if the browser will wait just so long before saying "moving on". I've stepped through the jquery js but cannot seem to find out where the result seems to null out.

Any help is appreciated. Note that if I use an ActionResult and pull down the larger data set, I've no issues with the page. It just takes forever and my strategy was to divide and conquer as I open a recursive list progressivly dependent on a users input. Obviously I can just round trip without ajax but that would be less attractive and I'm hoping I'm missing something here.

One other bit of info that might be helpful: if I put a "debugger" breakpoint in the "processJSON" function - the small set obviously hits it but the larger set does not. Which makes sense if there's a timeout issue. In either case, the button that kicks off the script can be clicked immediately. I.e., there's no lock up etc.

- thanks for any feedback.

---

SCRIPT CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({ 'async': false });
    $('#someButton').click(function () {
        $.get('GetJson', function (data) {
            processJSON(data);
        });
    });

    function processJSON(data) {
        var output = data;
        $('#SomeDiv').html(output);
    }
});
```

THE TWO .NET CONTROLLER FUNCTIONS:

```
        public JsonResult GetJson()
    {            
        JsonResult js = new JsonResult();
        TaxonomyHelper th = new TaxonomyHelper(1);
        js.Data =   "<script src='taxonomyRenderer.js' type='text/javascript'></script>" +
                    "<link href='taxonomyStyle.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />" +         
        th.TaxonomyDivTag.ToString();
        js.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        return js;
    }

    public JsonResult GetJsonAll()
    {
        JsonResult js = new JsonResult();
        TaxonomyHelper th = new TaxonomyHelper();
        js.Data = "<script src='taxonomyRenderer.js' type='text/javascript'></script>" +
                    "<link href='taxonomyStyle.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />" +
            th.TaxonomyDivTag.ToString();
        js.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        return js;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for new term, JasonResult. Never heard of it before. Who is Jason?

Comment: funny. but an answer would be more helpful LOL. One addition to this...I have added the code to pull out the subset of the large data set and it in fact works sometimes but not other..and always, when the JSON :) result is large-ish. So it does seem that there's either some sort of timeout or ideally a parameter I can set that says "I don't care how long..I'll wait". Thanks in advance for anything more than spellchecking LOL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `$.get()` timeout. See [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L322) which defaults to 0.

You are likely getting an error response, but it silently fails unless you attach something to the error handler. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062492/175679) describing how to connect your [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) error handler. jQuery is good at hiding errors for the convenience of the end user - not in favor of the developer.

If you know you are returning JSON, you should also use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: thanks. the error handler is of little help but does tell me it's a 500 error. And you are correct re the "getJSON". I'd tried that first but was just hunting around for some other reason and the code snippet had the "get". What I did notice is that while both work,the getJSON is way faster.

Comment: @LlewellynPreece - if you get a 500 response back than IIS has likely terminated your request execution. You may need to increase the `httpRuntime/@executionTimeout`. See [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use the low level ajax interface in JQuery instead of the short hand method
:- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> **timeout** Number
>   Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the request times out; accessing any object members may throw an exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

Comment: thanks for the response. Helpful but this is not it. I can emulate a timeout error. In fact, the ajax error handler (the exception parameter) will return a "timeout" error when that's the issue. It's not. But I did verify. The error is the illusive "500" server error. But I know there's no error in the server as the same return string works fine. There seems to be a size issue or something size related that's becoming more of a concerning because it would be useful to eval the size before returning to the server. I've added to the post details that might help. thanks again!

Comment: ic, how about setup an error trap? It should work when the status 200 is not received.