# jQuery GET fails with no error message

Tags: jquery, wcf, http-get

I'm making a `GET` request against a WCF web service. My WCF service is located at `http://localhost/RestService/RestService.svc/web/GetMessage` and has the following interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetMessage", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
String GetMessage();
```

The endpoint is configured properly as I can make a bare call within my browser:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp />
          </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service name="TestRestService.RestService"
               behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint name="RestWeb"
                  address="web"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="WebEndpointBehavior"
                  contract="TestRestService.IRestService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Calling it via navigation in my browser returns:

```
{"GetMessageResult":"Hello World!"}
```

So far so good. No problems here. A quick look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for performing a `GET` yields:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/RestService/RestService.svc/web/GetMessage',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, message) {
                    alert("Error: " + status + " " + message); }
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I run this in a small html test page using jQuery 1.72 and I get the following error:

```
Error: error
```

What gives? The error message handler [that I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062317/jquery-get-error-response-function) gives me *absolutely zero* useful information. Simply put:

- Why is my GET failing?
- Why is the error message useless?

## Solution

As it turns out, jQuery does not natively support cross-domain ajax requests as Kevin B [suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11265761/312124). To fix this I had to switch to using `dataType: 'jsonp'` and add a `webHttpBinding` with the `crossDomainScriptEnabled` property enabled:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebBindingWithScripts"
             crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<endpoint name="RestWeb"
          address="web"
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          behaviorConfiguration="WebEndpointBEhavior"
          bindingConfiguration="WebBindingWithScripts"
          contract="TestService.IRestService">
</endpoint>
```

When using only `dataType: 'jsonp'`, you will still get errors unless you configure your WCF service to allow cross domain scripts.

Comment: Try using Browser's devtool (For chrome ctrl+shift+J). Can you see the request going? Any errors on the console?

Comment: Try removing `dataType` and let jquery infer it.   You might also try setting `dataType: 'jsonp'`.

Comment: are you sure the web service is returning a MIME type of json/application?

Comment: @JohnKalberer: Removing `dataType` still gives me the same error. @ianpgall: I've added the signature of the service to the question. @Thrustmaster: I'll look into that.

Comment: @Thrustmaster: The error console and development console show no error messages for Firefox 13.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you making a cross-domain request? I see you are using localhost, but that doesn't necessarily mean you are requesting from localhost (for all we know you could be using a different port or protocol).

There are two reasons that the request would be failing in this case:

1. the JSON being returned has additional characters that makes it invalid json
2. the request is coming from a different domain than the webservice.

I expect it to be #1 due to you not seeing the `same-origin` error in the console. However, since you're getting `error` and not `parseerror`, that is unlikely.

Comment: I am making a local to local request. The page and service are on the same exact page. In fact, the page itself is just a simple html with the jQuery I posted above.

Comment: Correction: I mean to say the page and service are on the same exact *machine*. I will however try placing my test html page on my IIS server to see if that will change anything.

Comment: It was problem #2. I placed my html file on the IIS application hosting my service and it works fine. Is there any workaround if the IIS Service and webpage are on separate domains?

Comment: Yes, use JSONP rather than JSON.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me once, All I did was adding endpointBehaviors in my web.config to support WebHttp requests like this

```
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
   ......
   </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>   
  <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
```

and changed my endpoint to include "behaviorConfiguration" and changed binding

```
 <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService1" 
  behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior">
```

Dont forget to add this to your IService :

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Comment: My endpoint and endpoint behavior are (sans the contract name, endpoint behavior name) are the same. Would you like me to add the configuration to the question?

Comment: Please see my question. I have given a SSCE.