# jquery .get() seems to fail but cant get a message back

Tags: jquery

i have this `.get()` returning data that is fine from the URL but when it loops through and there isnt the required data at that URL it doesn't return an alert with `.error();` or even `.fail();`  want an action to happen if it cant find what its looking for, what have i done wrong?

```
$.get('/jsp/landing.jsp?id=FiresContent', function(data){


           var DataReturned = $(data).find('#' + topNavliID +' > div').each(function(index){

              SkuDetail = "<li id='" + index + "'><article><ul><li class='sku-" + index + "'>" + $(this).find('.sku').text() + "</li>";
              SkuDetail = SkuDetail + "<li class='prodName-" + index + "'><h2>" + $(this).find('.prodName').text() + "</h2></li>";
              SkuDetail = SkuDetail + "<li class='prodDesc-" + index + "'>" + $(this).find('.prodDesc').text() + "</li>";
              SkuDetail = SkuDetail + "<li class='action-" + index + "'><a href='" + $(this).find('.actionLink').text() + "' title='" + $(this).find('.action').text() + "'>" + $(this).find('.action').text() + "</a></li></ul></article></li>";

              ThumbNail = "<li class='thumbImage-" + index + "'><img src='/images/CAT110/FireSurrounds/thumbnail_" + $(this).find('.sku').text() + ".jpg' alt='" + $(this).find('.prodNameShort').text() + "' title='" + $(this).find('.prodNameShort').text() + "'>";
              ThumbNail = ThumbNail + "<span class='prodNameShort-" + index + "'>" + $(this).find('.prodNameShort').text() + "</span></li>";


              $('#largeSlides').css('width','+=1000');
              $('#largeSlides').append(SkuDetail);
              $('#thumbSlides').append(ThumbNail);

              // remove loading image once loaded.
              $('.loadingmessage').fadeOut(800, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                  });

           });
        }).fail(function(){ alert("$.get failed!"); });

        //.error(function() { alert("error"); });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062317/jquery-get-error-response-function

This question may help you out some.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using $.ajax instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

you get an easier error handling than by using $.get.

There is a lot of code snippets on that page.