# How to create cookie using jquery if PHP fails to load a particular URL content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

What is I'm missing in the following PHP+jQuery code

```
$ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
if(!isset($_COOKIE['isp'])){
    $ispinfo=@file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/".$ip_address."/org");
    if($ispinfo==FALSE){
    echo '<script>
    $.get( "http://ipinfo.io/'.$ip_address.'/org", function( data ) {
       var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "isp=" + data+ "; " + expires+ "; " + path=/";
    });

    </script>';
    } else {
    $isp_code_string = explode(" ",$ispinfo);
    $isp_code=$isp_code_string[0];
    $isp_name=str_replace($isp_code, '', $ispinfo);
    setcookie("isp", $isp_name, time()+10*365*24*60*60, "/");
    }
    } else {
    $isp_code_string = explode(" ",$_COOKIE["isp"]);
    $isp_code=$isp_code_string[0];
    $isp_name=str_replace($isp_code, '', $ispinfo);
    $isp_name="**".$isp_name;
    }
```

PHP is running fine but when `$ispinfo=@file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.o/".$ip_address."/org");` fails it is not creating cookie using the jQuery although the source of jQuery cum JS is appearing in the the source code (HTML) 
I have good knowledge about PHP but lacks about jQuery.
The problem with ipinfo.io is that it have limited IP access and Using jQuery I want to use user's IP to fetch and create cookie which can be later accessed.

Comment: If you want to handle errors you need to add error handling : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062317/jquery-get-error-response-function - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I don't want to handle the errors, I just want to create cookie based on above parameters.

Comment: But you say the cookie is not created when the get fails. That is correct according to your current design

Comment: Yeah jquery  is not creating cookie

Comment: What is the actual problem? The cookie does not get created since your code only executes when the get is successful- that can only be fixed using a fail or always event handler

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery and jQuery.Cookies I resolved the problem with following code

```
$ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
if(!isset($_COOKIE['isp'])){
    $ispinfo=@file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/".$ip_address."/org");
    if($ispinfo==FALSE){
    echo '<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
$.get( "http://ipinfo.io/'.$ip_address.'/org", function( data ) {
$.cookie("isp", data, { path: "/", expires: 7 });
$isp_name="jQ";

});
</script>';
    } else {
    $isp_code_string = explode(" ",$ispinfo);
    $isp_code=$isp_code_string[0];
    $isp_name=str_replace($isp_code, '', $ispinfo);
    setcookie("isp", $isp_name, time()+10*365*24*60*60, "/");
    }
    } else {
    $isp_code_string = explode(" ",$_COOKIE["isp"]);
    $isp_code=$isp_code_string[0];
    $isp_name=str_replace($isp_code, '', $ispinfo);
    $isp_name="**".$isp_name;
    }
```