# $.get always get unwanted string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to get a string form server using `$.get`

```
$.get("test.php", function(result) {
  if (result){
    alert("FOUND");
  } else {
    alert("NONE");
  }
});
```

php code is

```
<?php
    echo ""; //found nothing
?>
```

but the result is always "FOUND", i try to see what is returned from server using this code

```
var m = "";
for (var k=0; k < result.length; k++) {
    m += result.charCodeAt(k) + ",";
}
alert(m);
```

the result is : `9,13,10,9,13,10,`

no mater what string return from server, it always end with this string. what is the problem?

Comment: use the code formatting for code

Comment: It looks like you've got a couple of tabs and newlines in your php file.  Ensure `<?php` is _right_ at the start, and you can omit `?>` entirely to ensure you don't get any unwanted output.  Does that change the result?

Comment: You could also trim the string on the client side since it only contains whitespace.

Comment: it will always be true condition in if because you are not applying and other comparison what you want to achieve from this

Comment: @WisdmLabs An empty string in JavaScript is falsey.

Comment: yes empty string is false

Comment: @JamesThorpe write it as an answer!

Comment: Charcodes `9,13,10,9,13,10` mean `TAB CR LF TAB CR LF` which are two empty lines wit a leading `TAB`

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano It wasn't an answer at that point - just an idea of what _might_ be wrong.  OP has confirmed and already posted an answer to that effect now.

Comment: Duplicate:
See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062317/jquery-get-error-response-function

Answer (score 1):

i have found the reason ,there are two \t at the end of my php code.

Comment: also you can put   echo ""; die;

Comment: You could use `result = result.trim()` in the callback function to safeguard against leading and trailing whitespace (and all-whitespace response which seems to be the case here).

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax( "test.php" )
  .done(function(response) {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  });
```

If you want to check the ajax request is success or fail use this and if you want to check the response alert it and use it if you want like this `if(response=="")` your statement

Comment: Be careful -- PHP may return an error message with a 200  "success" status, so the done will run even though there is no test.php. You will need to look at the value in response to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: then we can check it  using response parameter

Comment: and at the end of every .php file we should write die() or else it will return 1 at the end