# jQuery $.get returns white error page when handling errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following code gives me an error like [this](http://cl.ly/image/1s2b1r1r2A1r) when I request a page and it comes back 404. Instead it should bring up an alert. What is strange is it **only does this on links that have been ajaxed in**, on links that don't update/change it works fine.

```
('.page-wrap').append('<img src="img/graphics/ajax-loader.gif" class="ajax-loader" />');

    var target = $('section.content'),
        siteURL = 'http://' + top.location.host.toString(),
        internalLinks = $("a[href^='"+siteURL+"'], a[href^='/'], a[href^='./'], a[href^='../'], a[href^='#']"),
        links = $('a'),
        URL,
        el,
        mainContent,
        headContent,
        headClasses,
        pageName,
        ajaxSpinner = $('.ajax-loader');
    internalLinks.click(function(e) {

        el = $(this);

        URL = el.attr('href');

        $('.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');
        el.addClass("current_link").parent().addClass("current_page_item");

        ajaxLoader(URL, false);

        e.preventDefault();

    });

    function ajaxLoader(location, isHistory) {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" });
            ajaxSpinner.show();
            $('.page-wrap').css('opacity', '0.5}');


            // Load New Page
            $.get(location, function(data) {
                mainContent = $('section.content', data).html();
                headContent = $('.feature-content', data).html();
                pageName = $('.page-name', data).html();
                headClasses = $('header', data).attr('class');
                $('section.content').html(mainContent);
                $('.page-name').html(pageName);
                $('.feature-content').html(headContent);
                if (headClasses) {
                    $('header').attr('class', headClasses);
                } else {
                    $('header').removeClass();
                }
                if (!isHistory) {
                    history.pushState(location, '', location);
                }

                $(resizeHeader);

                ajaxSpinner.fadeOut();
            }).error(function() {
                alert('woops'); // or whatever
            });
    }
    w.bind('popstate', function(event) {
        if (event.originalEvent.state !== null ) {
            ajaxLoader(event.originalEvent.state, true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: I am trying to load pages with AJAX and if there are errors(e.g 404) then it will notify the user, the code above worked but after I added the `.error` part its starts bringing up errors.

Comment: @George, what is the purpose of these lines:  `mainContent = $('section.content', data).html();` etc? I can't see why need them....

Comment: The output (data) from the ajax request is a string of HTML, these lines take out the parts of HTML I need to update because I don't want to replace the document. However, I discovered the issue only occurs on links that have been ajaxed in.

Answer (score 1):

First thoughts

- Is it perhaps the case that something in your success handler code is causing an error of some kind? Like maybe the injection of whatever html that comes back the first successful time is causing the script to fail a second time?
- What do you see playing out in your your Fiddler/Firebug/F12 developer tool of choice  - you are using one of these, right? :) Keep an eye on any console errors...

Second thought

What jQuery version are you using?

I have tested this with jq 1.8.2 and the error handler works just fine for me, but if this is a JSONP request it won't trigger the error() function. I took the gist of your code:

```
$.get(
               "404MeBaby.html", function (data) {
                   $(".result").html(data);
                   console.log(data);
               }
            ).error(
            function (x) {
                console.log("well that didn't go so well...");
            });
```

From the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

> As of jQuery 1.5, the success callback function is also passed a
>   "jqXHR" object (in jQuery 1.4, it was passed the XMLHttpRequest
>   object). However, since JSONP and cross-domain GET requests do not use
>   XHR, in those cases the jqXHR and textStatus parameters passed to the
>   success callback are undefined.

You could try using `$.ajax` instead as it gives a lot more control. Or, you can set the jQuery global ajax options as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175756/how-to-handle-error-in-get) that will affect all $.get calls, but remember the curse of JSONP, if relevant!

Comment: As expected, this is the error it gave me and nothing more (http://cl.ly/image/2E2l1Y41051s). I am running jQuery 1.9.1. I have played around with it and worked out that it is the line: 
$('section.content').html(mainContent);
That causes the error. I will look to see if its my HTML which is causing the error but I am not sure why?

Comment: @George, can you post up here what is the value of mainContent that you are injecting into that element - from your code this overwrites the ajax target, yes? Let's see if there is something funny in what's being written to that element..

Comment: I have done this, to me there doesn't seem to be anything dodgy. Its just HTML. Could it be something to do with the fact that the link was not there when the document was first created ? I changed one of the links that was is intact after ajax and it fits this conclusion. 
Do you have any suggestions to things that might fix this ?

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but are you 100% certain that the link is actually accessible - if you try to open the url shown in the debugger screenshot, does it open?